# Can't select inner join data from MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I can't select inner join data from MYSQL in Java.

I'm using this code in Java:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/despesas?useSSL=true", "root", "local"); 
Statement comando = conexao.createStatement();
String sqlInsert;
ResultSet rsTDP;
sqlInsert = "select id_historico, tipos_de_despesas.descricao, dt_desp, valor_despesa from tipos_de_despesas INNER JOIN historico_despesas ON tipos_de_despesas.id_despesa=historico_despesas.id_despesa ORDER BY dt_desp desc";
rsTDP = comando.executeQuery(sqlInsert);
while(rsTDP.next()){
    System.out.println("ID da Despesa: " + rsTDP.getString("id_despesa") + " | Descrição: " + rsTDP.getString("descricao"));
}
```

This sintax works in MYSQL Workbench but in Java does not.

```
SELECT id_historico, tipos_de_despesas.descricao, dt_desp, valor_despesa from tipos_de_despesas INNER JOIN historico_despesas ON tipos_de_despesas.id_despesa=historico_despesas.id_despesa ORDER BY dt_desp desc
```

[This is result in Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKKPW.png)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does not work in Java means?

Comment: Are you getting an error or just not getting any results?

Comment: Note that in the Workbench it does not return any SELECT data, but in Java it returns a SQLException. You should return all data in the Java console just as it does in the Workbench.

Comment: So you get a SQLException that talks about Java console and Workbench? I am confused.

Comment: No i get a SQLException on Java console only.

Comment: Sure but what is the Message of the Exception?

Comment: Yes can you catch and then show us the message of the SQLException `try{}catch(SQLException ex){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage()};`

Comment: @abcOfJavaAndCPP That throws away a lot of the relevant information (ie the stacktrace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bet the exception is actually coming from this line:

```
System.out.println("ID da Despesa: " + rsTDP.getString("id_despesa") + " | Descrição: " + rsTDP.getString("descricao"));
```

I don't see the `id_despesa` column in the select statement and the `ResultSet` can only read columns from the select statement. So the `rsTDP.getString("id_despesa")` will throw a `SQLException`.

If you don't need the `id_despesa` column, then you can just leave it out of the `println`. Otherwise, you can change your SQL to this:

```
sqlInsert = "select tipos_de_despesas.id_despesa, id_historico, tipos_de_despesas.descricao, dt_desp, valor_despesa from tipos_de_despesas INNER JOIN historico_despesas ON tipos_de_despesas.id_despesa=historico_despesas.id_despesa ORDER BY dt_desp desc";
```

With the column added to the query, then you will be able to get `id_despesa` out of the results.